# Тип переменной, автоматическое значение

Tags: c++

Всем привет, начал изучать **template**. И вот столкнулся с такой делемой. Написал я шаблонную функцию для свапа значения a->b, b->a. Она принимает любое значение. Так вот, суть моего вопроса.
У меня есть main.В нем я хочу объявить переменную не int, double или же string, а чтобы когда я пытался что-то записать в нее в стандартном потоке ввода cin, компилятор сам присвоил бы этой переменной тип данных.
Я погуглил, нашел такой тип данных как auto, но если написать auto temp;
std::cin >> temp;
Выдаст ошибку.
Хочу что-то наподобие ниже.

```
template<typename T>
void swap(T &a, T &b) {
    T temp;
    temp = b;
    b = a;
    a = temp;
}
int main() {
    auto temp1, temp2;
    std::cin >> temp >> temp2;
    swap(temp1, temp2);
    std::cout << "temp1:" << temp1 << " temp2:" << temp2 << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Приведите код текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: Компилятор компилирует код до того как программа (скомпилированная программа) увидит ввод. И конкретные типы должны быть определены тогда же. Ваша задача в таком виде не разрешима. Её можно решить без помощи компилятора, но код будет куда более лохматый.

Comment: С точки зрения пользователя вашей программы, вам достаточно работать со строками. Разные типы просто не нужны.

Comment: Поставьте себя на место компилятора. Например, сколько байт выделить для переменной `temp1`? Один? Четыре? Как читать в переменную: просто как строку? Как число? Например, 123+321 - это два числа и символ? Одна строка? Число с опечаткой внутри? Ответьте на эти вопросы, они не риторические!

Comment: `auto` это не тип данных, а лишь указание компилятору "выбирай сам какой тип этой переменной сделать по ее инициализации", а посколько вы не инициализируете переменную, то и компилятор вашего указания не понимает

Comment: Вы ищите `std::variant<int, double, std::string>`. Только вот разбирать по входной строке, что именно вам пришло, придется самостоятельно.